# Converting csv to json file format but not getting expected output

Tags: python, json, pandas

I need to convert csv to json file format but output not getting as expected. Line1, Line2 and etc getting repeated in json output. I need to remove those repeated part.

**Input data**

```
7,priya,kannan,shanthapriya794@gmail.com,07-12-1994,"123","456",67,mdu,tn,india
7,priya,kannan,shanthapriya7964@gmail.com,07-12-1994,"123","456",67,mdu,tn,india
```

**Expected output**

```
[ {
    "source_id": 7,
    "fname": "priya",
    "lname": "kannan",
    "date_of_birth": "07-12-1994",
    "email": ["shanthapriya794@gmail.com", "shanthapriya7964@gmail.com"],
    "address": [{
        "line1": 123,
        "line2": 456,
        "line3": 67,
        "city": "mdu",
        "state": "tn",
        "country": "india"
    }]
}]
```

**Output getting**

```
[ {
    "source_id": 7,
    "fname": "priya",
    "lname": "kannan",
    "date_of_birth": "07-12-1994",
    "email": ["shanthapriya794@gmail.com", "shanthapriya7964@gmail.com"],
    "address": [{
        "line1": 123,
        "line2": 456,
        "line3": 67,
        "city": "mdu",
        "state": "tn",
        "country": "india"
    }, {
        "line1": 123,
        "line2": 456,
        "line3": 67,
        "city": "mdu",
        "state": "tn",
        "country": "india"
    }]
}]
```

**Code tried**

```
g_cols = ['source_id', 'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'date_of_birth']
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=",", header=0)

cols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(g_cols)]
g_cols.remove('email')

df = (df.sort_values(g_cols)
      .set_index(g_cols)
      .assign(email=df.groupby(g_cols)['email'].agg(lambda x: tuple(pd.unique(x))))
      .reset_index())

g_cols.append('email')
df1 = df.groupby(g_cols)[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(name='address').to_dict('record')
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In This step use `drop_duplicates()` method:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(g_cols)[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(name='address').to_dict('record')
```

output of `df1`:

```
[{'source_id': 7,
  'fname': 'priya',
  'lname': 'kannan',
  'date_of_birth': '07-12-1994',
  'email': ('shanthapriya794@gmail.com', 'shanthapriya7964@gmail.com'),
  'address': [{'ln1': 123,
    'ln2': 456,
    'ln3': 67,
    'cty': 'mdu',
    'state': 'tn',
    'cntry': 'india'}]}]
```

Comment: Can you please help me on this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921025/converting-the-csv-file-to-specified-json-format?noredirect=1#comment121803984_68921025

Answer (score 0):

```
g_cols = ['source_id', 'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'date_of_birth']
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=",", header=0)

cols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(g_cols)]
g_cols.remove('email')

df = (df.sort_values(g_cols)
      .set_index(g_cols)
      .assign(email=df.groupby(g_cols)['email'].agg(lambda x: tuple(pd.unique(x))))
      .reset_index())

g_cols.append('email')
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(g_cols)[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(name='address').to_dict('record')
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
```