# Converting the CSV file to specified Json format

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python and don't know how to achieve this. I am trying to convert CSV file to JSON format. Address have types 1. Primary 2. Work and Address is multi value attribute as well. Person can have 2 Primary address.

**Input Data in CSV format**

```
"f_name"|"l_name"|"address_type"|"address_line_1"|"city"|"state"|"postal_code"|"country"
Brad|Pitt|Primary|"18 Atherton"|Irvine|CA|"92620-2501"|USA
Brad|Pitt|work|"1325 S Grand Ave"|Santa Ana|CA|"92705-4406"|USA
```

**Output Expecting in JSON Format**

```
{
   "f_name": "Brad",
   "l_name": "Pitt",
   "parsed_address": [
      {
         "address_type": "Primary",
         "address": [
            {
               "address_line_1": "18 Atherton",
               "city": "Irvine",
               "state": "CA",
               "postal_code": "92620-2501",
               "country": "USA"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_type": "work",
         "address": [
            {
               "address_line_1": "1325 S Grand Ave",
               "city": "Santa Ana",
               "state": "CA",
               "postal_code": "92620-2501",
               "country": "USA"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Code Tried**

```
df = pd.read_csv("file")

g_cols = ['f_name','l_name']
address_field = ['address']
cols = ['address_line_1', 'address_line_2', 'address_line_3', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'country']

for i in g_cols:
    if i in dict_val.keys():
        g_cols[g_cols.index(i)] = dict_val[i]

for i in cols:
    if i in dict_val.keys():
        cols[cols.index(i)] = dict_val[i]
        
df2 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(g_cols)[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(
        name=address_field).to_dict('record')
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana I don't have any clue how to get the output.

Comment: One step at a time: Read the data, transform it, get the output. I suggest you use a csv.DictReader to read in your data; then you just need to convert one dictionary template to another.

Comment: Ok, sorry, but stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Instead its a `What did I do wrong in my code?` service.

Comment: @alexis, Data read is fine but i need to form the address field from multiple subfield that i am not sure how to do. In address I have address_type as well.

Comment: Then show the code you have for reading the data, etc. That way you can get help that builds on what you have, not a complete program.

Comment: @quamrana, agreed with you.

Comment: let me edit my question with code part

Comment: Anyway, `parsed_address` and `address` are lists containing a single dictionary. Construct a fresh dictionary for each one, and populate it from the input data.

Comment: I have updated my  code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You were close. This should do too exactly what aim to do.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep="|")
df
```

[image]

```
dic = {}
for name, group in df.groupby(by=["name"]):
    dic["name"] = name
    dic["parsed_address"] = []
        for address_type, group in df.groupby(by=["address_type"]):
            address_dic = {}
            address_dic["address_type"] = address_type
            address_dic["address"] = group.drop(columns=["name", "address_type"]).to_dict(orient="records")
            dic["parsed_address"].append(address_dic)
dic
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @ananay.. I need to make configurable code and there are n number of columns with name(gender,first_name ,last_name) and address(email and phone).

Comment: Updated my data and code. Added l_name in the data and code.

Comment: Now I agree with the comment section above. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Instead its a `What did I do wrong` in my code? service. I have helped you get close to your solution but I won't hand hold/spoon feed you to it. I am paid to do that

Comment: Thanks @Ananay.. I am very close to the solution now. I will post my answer soon.

Comment: I am not asking for spoon feed or something else. I am struck there. I am new to python as well so learning and working

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try having a dictionary or list (`json_data` in the code below) to keep track of a person's data and iterating throw each row of the dataframe using `for _, row in df.iterrows():`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file", delimiter='|')
print(df)

json_data = {}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    name = row["name"]
    address_type = row["address_type"]
    address_line_1 = row["address_line_1"]
    city = row["city"]
    state = row["state"]
    postal_code = row["postal_code"]
    country = row["country"]
    if name not in json_data:
        json_data[name] = {
            "name": name,
            "parsed_address": []
        }

    address_list = None 
    for address in json_data[name]["parsed_address"]:
        if address["address_type"] == address_type:
            address_list = address
    
    if address_list is None:
        address_list = {
            "address_type": address_type,
            "address": []
        }
        json_data[name]["parsed_address"].append(address_list)
    
    address_list["address"].append({
        "address_line_1": address_line_1,
        "city": city,
        "state": state,
        "postal_code": postal_code,
        "country": country
    })

lst = list(json_data.values())

# Verify data parsing
import json
print(json.dumps(lst, indent=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {}
g_cols = ['id','first_name','last_name','address_type]
    for name, group in df.groupby(g_cols)["address"]:
        id = name[0]
        dic["id"] = id
        dic["parsed_address"] = []
        for address_type, group in df.groupby(by=["address_type"]):
            address_dic = {}
            address_dic["address_type"] = address_type
            address_dic["address"] = group.drop(
                columns=["id", "first_name","last_name","address_type"]).to_dict("record")
            dic["parsed_address"].append(address_dic)
```